# Plotting more than 10K points using gcurve

Tags: vpython

When i append all the 10K points and use gcurve its not plotting all of them. I know only 1000 points of the 10K have been plotted.
My python version is 2.7.6
I don't know how to fix this.

In future i am gonna make a data set of more than 30K and use gcurve.
How to plot more than 1k points in gcurve.

Can you please help m ein htis.

Thnaks.